# Javascript refactoring and cleaning up helper function code

Tags: javascript, string, function, format

Im working on an app that uses a few helper functions that I've created to format data coming in.  Below is the code that I've made.  It all works, and does what it's supposed to, but I'm hoping for some help with making the code a bit more efficient.. I feel that it could be cleaned up a bit.

```
// Convert to Title Case
export function toTitleCase(str) {
  return str.replace(/\w\S*/g, function (txt) {
    return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase();
  });
}

// Convert date from ISO-8601 to toDateString without time
export function formatDate(dateData) {
  const date = new Date(dateData);
  const formattedDate = date.toDateString();
  return formattedDate;
}

// Convert date from ISO-8601 to toDateString with time
export function formatDateWithTime(dateData) {
  const date = new Date(dateData);
  const formattedDate = date.toLocaleString();
  return formattedDate;
}
```

Comment: Since your code works, I think that this question is more appropriate for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: something like `return new Date(dateData).toLocaleString()` maybe

Comment: Capitalize first letter:  `return str.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + str.slice(1);`

Comment: If your goal is to reduce lines of code and you are ok with arrow functions, you could condense your code into 3 lines:
`export const toTitleCase = (str) => str.replace(/\w\S*/g, (txt) => txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase())`
`export const formatDate = (dateData) => new Date(dateData).toDateString()`
`export const formatDateWithTime = (dateData) => new Date(dateData).toLocaleString()`